# Episerver: Sortable iList<string> not displaying correctly on Azure

Tags: c#, content-management-system, episerver

**I have a sortalbe ilist(string) displaying correctly locally:**

[image]

**However, this is NOT display correctly on integration. Instead it's displaying as tags?**

[image]

Comment: I think the second one is a custom editor, I think it might be based on this: https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2016/custom-editor-for-string-list-properties-in-episerver/

Are you sure it's the same source code version in both environments?

If so, could you try "Revert to default" in admin mode for the "Meta Global Keywords" property in the Integration environment?

Comment: The custom editor isn't really needed anymore since Episerver now has a native editor for value lists.

Comment: Thank you @TedNyberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by removing:

- Business\Descriptors\StringsEditorDescriptor.cs

and by adding:

- ClientResources\Scripts\Editors\ExtendedCollectionEditor.js
- ClientResources\Scripts\Editors\extendedFormatters.js
- ClientResources\Scripts\Editors\ExtendedPropertyList.js

Comment: Those shouldn't be needed for `IList<string>` properties: https://world.episerver.com/blogs/bartosz-sekula/dates/2017/10/property-value-list/